# How to store int in char * in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers, char, memcpy

Can anyone help converting the Int to char array 
as i have buffer as

```
char *buffer = NULL;  
int lengthOfComponent = -1;   
char *obj;
buffer[index]= (char *)&lengthOfComponent;
```

if i do this it is thorwing EXCESS BAD ACCESS **after the execution how to store the value of the obj to buffer using memcpy**

Comment: Use sprintf or printf, or NSLog or NSString stringWithFormat.

Comment: This isn't iphone or objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you cannot write in buffer[index], it is not allocated!

```
buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * lengthOfBuffer);
```

should do it. After that you can write the buffer with memcpy or with an assignation, like you are doing.

Comment: how to copy the obj[i] to buffer using memcopy

Answer (score 0):

```
buffer[index] = (char *)&lengthOfComponent;
```

`buffer[index]` is like dereferencing the pointer. But `buffer` is not pointing to any valid location. Hence the runtime error.

The C solution is using snprintf. Try -

```
int i = 11;
char buffer[10];

snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", i);
```

Comment: `Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char *'; dereference with *` it is throwing this warning

Comment: It is exactly what is mentioned in the answer. `buffer[index]` gives the character at the index location but not the pointer. The question is why do you want a character pointer to point to an integer location.

Comment: basically i want the length of component value to store in the buffer[index] please help me out doing this